# Load xib from storyboard view is main is messed up

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationbar

I am loading one xib while my complete app is in storyboard, by simply

```
LBNewReuqestController *viewController=[[LBNewReuqestController alloc]init];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

But when xib loads it starts view much higher means it's not considering simulated Navigation bar , so for making it ok I have to start views bit lower like
[image]

so why do I need to start views bit lower to adjust the position of views?

Comment: Uncheck 'Use Auto Layout'

Comment: already unchecked , xib but i have use in storybaord

Comment: U might changed the view programmatically?

Comment: no i did not changed any thing